# finding greater numbers in a java array

Tags: java, arrays, return-value

**Problems are:**

1. finding greater numbers in an array
2. returning the index number that contains greater value instead of index value.

**Code**

```
public class temp02 {

 public static void consoledisplay(int [] array){
  for (int a = 0; a < array.length; a++)
   System.out.println("Value of array index "+a+" is "+array[a]);
  System.out.println("");
 }

 public static int [] higherNumbers(int[] array, int numbers){
  // needed codes here
  return array;
 }

 public static void main (String[] args) {
  int [] x = new int[10];
  x[0] = 55;
  x[1] = 27;
  x[2] = 23;
  x[3] = 22;
  x[4] = 55;
  x[5] = 56;
  x[6] = 33;
  x[7] = 21;
  x[8] = 21;
  x[9] = 99;

  consoledisplay(x);

  x = higherNumbers(x,4);
  consoledisplay(x);
 }
}
```

**Current Output**

Value of array index 0 is 55
Value of array index 1 is 27
Value of array index 2 is 23
Value of array index 3 is 22
Value of array index 4 is 55
Value of array index 5 is 56
Value of array index 6 is 33
Value of array index 7 is 21
Value of array index 8 is 21
Value of array index 9 is 99

Value of array index 0 is 55
Value of array index 1 is 27
Value of array index 2 is 23
Value of array index 3 is 22
Value of array index 4 is 55
Value of array index 5 is 56
Value of array index 6 is 33
Value of array index 7 is 21
Value of array index 8 is 21
Value of array index 9 is 99

**Target Output**

Value of array index 0 is 55
Value of array index 1 is 27
Value of array index 2 is 23
Value of array index 3 is 22
Value of array index 4 is 55
Value of array index 5 is 56
Value of array index 6 is 33
Value of array index 7 is 21
Value of array index 8 is 21
Value of array index 9 is 99

Value of array index 0 is 9
Value of array index 1 is 5
Value of array index 2 is 0
Value of array index 3 is 4

Comment: Seems like some kind of homework to me... shouldn't you solve that yourself?

Comment: i am no longer attending school. it is actually a part of my personal project. i already fried my brain.

Answer (score 0):

```
int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[max])
                max = i;
        }
        return max;
```

Comment: i tried this but still doesn't work.<br>

public static int [] higherNumbers(int[] array, int numbers){<br>
int [] finalArray = new int[numbers];<br>
finalArray[0] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;<br>
for (int a=0; a < numbers; a++){<br>
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){<br>
if (array[i] >= finalArray[a])<br>
finalArray[a] = i;<br>
}<br>
}<br>
return finalArray;<br>
}<br>

Comment: the way of finding the max value is that i said, and you dont need to use static

Comment: sorry man, your code doesn't work.
the needed return value is int [].
the return int [] should contain 4 greater integers, not just one.

and the static needs to be declared otherwise the compiler is saying this "non-static method higherNumbers(int[],int) cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: you asked for `finding greater numbers in a java array` and i say with power that it is the answer , if you want to do something else change the title but for that title it is the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static int[] higherNumbers(int[] array, int numbers) {
    int tempArr[] = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    Arrays.sort(tempArr);
    int retArr[] = new int[numbers];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = array.length - numbers; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            if (array[x] == tempArr[i]) {
                retArr[j] = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    return retArr;
}
```

Comment: i change the values in int[]x={0,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9};, on main method, to test your wonderful method but the output looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

use following code, it will work

```
public static int[] higherNumbers(int[] array, int numbers) {
    int tempArr[] = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);
    Arrays.sort(tempArr);
    int retArr[] = new int[numbers];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = array.length - numbers; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
            if (array[x] == tempArr[i]) {
                if(checkIndex(retArr,x)){
                continue;
                }else{
                    retArr[j] = x;
                break;
                }
            }
        }
        j++;
    }
    return retArr;
}

private static boolean checkIndex(int[] indexArr, int index){
    boolean status = false;
    for(int i=0; i<indexArr.length; i++){
        if(index == indexArr[i]){
            status = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Comment: now this is a complete and clean answer! super cool man! you are very smart! thank you very very much!!!